# weak node js module error on windows 7

Tags: node.js, npm, weak-references

I have installed all the necessary requirements for the node-gyp for windows 7 from the link below
https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

I am trying to install weak nodeJS module , but I am facing the below error

```
weakref.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)
class v8::Handle<class v8::Value> __cdecl node::MakeCallback(class v8::Handle<c
lass v8::Object>,class v8::Handle<class v8::Function>,int,class v8::Handle<clas
s v8::Value> * const)" (__imp_?MakeCallback@node@@YA?AV?$Handle@VValue@v8@@@v8@
@V?$Handle@VObject@v8@@@3@V?$Handle@VFunction@v8@@@3@HQEAV23@@Z) [D:\node_modul
es\weak\build\weakref.vcxproj]
D:\node_modules\weak\build\Release\weakref.node : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unreso
lved externals [D:\node_modules\weak\build\weakref.vcxproj]
```

I have nodeJS 64 bit. I am unable to figure out the problem. If anyone has a solution much appreciated.

**EDIT**
After updating to node v0.10.24 from v0.10.0 I am now getting the below error

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'kernel32.lib' [D:\node_modu
les\weak\build\weakref.vcxproj]
```

Thanks

Comment: file this issue with node-gyp and the weak module, too. this is a potential bug (even if just missing documentation on dependencies for windows) and the authors should be notified by you.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans on one of my machines I have succesfully installed weak module ,but while trying the same on the other machine, facing the above error. So I think some file is missing on the machine causing the failure. Are you sure it is a bug related to weak or node-gyp....?

Comment: I suspect it's a documentation issue. if you installed all the node-gyp-indicated dependencies and it won't compile, then either node-gyp or weak (probably the latter) is missing documentation that allows you to successfully compile. file bugs, worst case they will go "this is not our problem" and you can narrow your search for where it really is.

Comment: Latest version of node? http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.24/x64/node.exe

Comment: @damphat 0.10.0 node version

Comment: @CrazyNooB you are at patch-0, it is now patch-24.

Comment: @damphat I m taking the latest now

Comment: @damphat after updating to new patch , I am now getting the error LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'kernel32.lib' [D:\node_modu
les\weak\build\weakref.vcxproj]

Comment: @CrazyNooB is this work? `npm update -g node-gyp`

Comment: @damphat I will let you know soon. Currently I m uninstalling all visual c++ and windows sdk and installing again

Comment: @damphat I have updated node-gyp but still the same issue.